# Proving the Weak Continuity Property is Equivalent to the Continuity Property (in Cohomology)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Edwin H. Spanier's *Algebraic Topology*, he describes both a "continuity property" and a "weak continuity property" for cohomology theories. (He actually defines these in terms of pairs $(X,A)$ where $A$ is some subspace of $X$, but I don't care about this; I just want to understand this for spaces.)

First of all, if $\lbrace X_i,p_{ij} \rbrace_{i,j\in I}$ is an inverse system of compact Hausdorff spaces and $X:=\varprojlim X_i$, then for *any* cohomology theory $H^*(\bullet)$ the projection maps $p_{ij}:X_j\to X_i$ induce maps $p_{ij}^*:H^k(X_i)\to H^k(X_j)$ which form a direct system of groups/modules; furthermore the maps $p_i:X\to X_i$ induce maps $p_i^*:H^k(X_i)\to H^k(X)$ which are compatible with that direct system, so we obtain a map $p^*:\varinjlim H^k(X_i)\to H^k(X)$. If the map $p^*$ is an isomorphism, then the cohomology theory is called "continuous".

Next, if every $X_i$ is a subspace of some ambient space (let's say $Y$) and every projection map $p_{ij}:X_j \to X_i$ is just the inclusion of $X_j$ as a subspace of $X_i$, then actually $X=\underset{i\in I}{\bigcap}X_i$ and each $p_i:X\to X_i$ is also inclusion. I'll call this situation a "nested system", as I think I've seen that terminology for it elsewhere. If $p^*$ is an isomorphism *just* for nested systems, then the cohomology theory is called "weakly continuous".

Spanier says that "it is not hard to prove that the continuity property is equivalent to the weak continuity property". Well, one direction (continuity implies weak continuity) is trivial, but I have a gap in attempting to prove the *other* direction.

Let's say a cohomology theory satisfies weak continuity, and I have some inverse system of compact Hausdorff spaces. What appears to be the obvious way to reconstruct this as a nested system is to make the ambient space $Y:=\underset{i\in I}{\prod } X_i$ since $X$ is already constructed as a subspace of this, and then make a nested system $\lbrace Y_i \rbrace_{i \in I}$ by fixing some basepoint $b\in X$ and making each $Y_i$ equal to the product of $\underset{i\leq j}{\prod}X_{j}$ with the "$X_k$" components of the base point for all $k<i$. With this, I can make the natural projection maps $\pi_j:\underset{i\in I}{\prod } X_i\to X_j$, which are surjective, give me an injective map $\pi^*:\varinjlim H^*(X_i)\to\varinjlim(Y_i)\cong H^*(X)$ (where the last isomorphism is because $H^*(\bullet)$ is weakly continuous). But here I get stuck, because I can't see any way to either show that this map is also surjective or make an injective map going the other way. Any map I can easily think of seems to be going the wrong direction to complete the needed isomorphism. So, what am I missing?

Comment: Edwin H. Spanier.

Comment: Sorry, I had Alexander-Spanier Cohomology on the brain. Fixed.

Comment: In a footnote Spanier gives a reference to Eilenberg and Steenrod's "Foundations of Algebraic Topology" and to exercise 6.C.2. I suggest to have a look at the hints in the exercise and try to add details. If you do not succeed, make an update to your question and tell us which concrete problems you have.

Comment: The exercise has no hints, it literally (figuratively) just says "ok now prove that." And I had a look in the relevant-looking section of Eilenberg and Steenrod's book, but there doesn't seem to be anything there regarding this particular issue. They describe nested systems in a bit more detail, but that isn't particularly helpful. And I already said what my concrete problem was: I need a map going the other way or some other way to show that p^* is an isomorphism in this situation.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how my question fails to give enough detail. In fact, while writing it I felt like maybe it was too long, but I didn't want to leave out any relevant information.

Comment: You are right, Spanier's footnote refers to 6.C.2 which doesn't say much. But it obviously was a typo, you find everything in 6.C.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excercise 6.C.1 Spanier gives the following hint (he does it for pairs, here we only consider the absolute case):

> Prove that $X$ can be embedded in a space in which it is a directed intersection of compact Hausdorff spaces $X'_i$ where $X'_i$ has the same homotopy type as $X_i$. Hint: For each $k \in I$ embed $X_k$ in a contractible compact Hausdorff space $Y_k$, for example a cube, and let $X'_i \subset \prod_{k \in I} Y_k$ be defined as the set of all points $(y_k)$ with $y_i \in X_i$ and $y_j = p_{ji}(y_i)$ for $j \le i$. All other coordinates $y_j$ are arbitrary.

Let us analyze this. W.l.o.g. we may assume $X_k \subset Y_k$ as a genuine subset with inclusion map $\iota_k : X_k \to Y_k$. Let $P_i = \prod_{k \le i} Y_k$ and let $\pi_k : P_i \to Y_k$ denote the projections for $k \le i$. Moreover let $Q_i = \prod_{k \not\le i} Y_k$, and let $q_k :  P = \prod_{j \in I} Y_j \to Y_k$ denote the projections.

1. There is a unique map $\phi_i : X_i \to P_i$ such that $\pi_k \phi_i = \iota_k p_{ki}$. It is injective since $\pi_i \phi_i = \iota_i$. Because $X_i$ is compact  and $P_i$ is Hausdorff, $\phi_i$ is an embedding and thus gives a homeomorphism $\phi'_i : X_i \to X''_i = \phi_i(X_i)$. The inverse homeomorphism is nothing else than the restriction $r_i : X''_i \to X_i$ of $\pi_i$. Clearly $X'_i = X''_i \times Q_i$. Since $Q_i$ is contractible, the map $R_i = r_i q_i : X'_i \to X_i$ with projection $q_i : X''_i \times Q_i \to X''_i$ is a homotopy equivalence. By construction, $R_i$ is nothing else than the restriction of $q_i$ to $X'_i$.
2. For $l \le i$ we have $X'_i \subset X'_l$. This is clear because $X_i$ is the set of all  $(y_k)$ with $y_i \in X_i$ and $y_j = p_{ji}(y_i)$ for $j \le i$. Each such $(y_j)$ has $y_l = p_{li}(y_i) \in X_l$ and $p_{jl}(y_l) = p_{jl}(p_{li}(y_i)) = p_{ji}(y_i) =y_j$ for $j \le l$, thus $(y_j) \in X'_l$. By $e_{li} : X'_i \to X'_l$ we denote the inclusion map.
3. We have
   $$\varprojlim X'_i = \bigcap_{i \in I} X'_i = \{(y_j) \mid y_j \in X_j \text{ for all } j, p_{kj}(y_j) = y_k \text{ for all } k \le j \}  \\=  \{(y_j) \in \prod_{j \in I} X_j \mid p_{kj}(y_j) = y_k \text{ for all } k \le j \} = \varprojlim X_i = X .$$
4. For $l \le i$ we have $R_l e_{li} = p_{li} R_i$. In fact, for $(y_j) \in X'_i$ we have
   $$R_l e_{li}((y_j)) = R_l((y_j)) = q_l((y_j)) = y_l = p_{li}(y_i) = p_{li}(q_i((y_j))) =  p_{li}(R_i((y_j))) .$$

Thus the $R_i$ form a map of inverse systems from $(X'_i,e_{ji})$ to $(X_i,p_{ji})$ such that all $R_i^*$ are isomorphisms of cohomology groups. The desired result follows.

Comment: Since I was laser-focused on the exercise Spanier specifically pointed to, I essentially didn't even see the one right before it, much less the fact that the two were related. Thanks for your patience with me.